# OpenGL on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: graphics, opengl

On a Dell XPS 13 with preinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 I have problems to get OpenGL example programs (www.opengl-tutorial.org) running. Everything compiles fine, however the window on the screen either is black or shows some artefacts.
Mesa seems to be up-to-date and should be able to understand OpenGL 3.3;

```
$ glxinfo | grep version
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30

$glxinfo | grep renderer
GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer,
GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer,
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Broadwell
```

Full output of glxinfo: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11364260

```
  $lshw -C display
   *-display               
   Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
   Produkt: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
   Hersteller: Intel Corporation
   Physische ID: 2
   Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:02.0
   Version: 09
   Breite: 64 bits
   Takt: 33MHz
   Fähigkeiten: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   Konfiguration: driver=i915 latency=0
   Ressourcen: irq:64 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(Größe=64)
```

Any idea, what I can do to use OpenGL?

Thanks,
Helmar

Comment: A more complete output of `glxinfo` *(you may need to use http://paste.ubuntu.com)* and `lshw -C graphics` may help - opengl should work out of the box I find, just it is often a old version(s). Using a new version may be difficult as parts of the system may only work with the old version.

Comment: I added the full glxinfo output and the display information.
glxgears works as expected, however the Qt 5.2.1 OpenGL examples show the same behavior like those of the opengl tutorial.